# How to "rebase" a single commit?

Tags: git

Consider the following tree:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F --- master
 \
  \
    B' --- C' --- D' --- topic
```

where `(B != B')`. I would like to do `git rebase --onto master master topic` but this generates conflicts. But the situation is simpler: I would like to put the single `topic` commit onto master.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick topic
git checkout topic
git reset --hard master
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Isn't it possible to do with a single command the commands above?

Comment: Why not just fix the conflicts ?

Comment: because actually there are no conflicts...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git rebase a single commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635672/git-rebase-a-single-commit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset your branch first, then use the reflog to find the commit to cherry pick:

```
git checkout -B topic master # re-create topic branch at the commit of master
git cherry-pick topic@{1} # copy the old tip of the topic branch
```

---

Another – maybe even simpler – way would be to pass rebase a range of commits which only consists of the single commit you want to have rebased:

```
git rebase --onto master topic^ topic
```

Comment: if I understand the `-B` flag correctly, the second cherry-pick should say that there's nothing to do, because it try to pick the same commit master is pointing to, I think `topic@{1}` should be replaced by the direct hash of the commit, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady: `topic@{1}` refers to the previous commit the branch pointed to. Before the checkout/reset it pointed at `D'`, after the checkout it points at `F`. `topic@{0}` would be `F`, `topic@{1}` would be `D'` and `topic@{2}` would be whatever commit pointed to before `D'` (most probably `C'`

Comment: hm, this is interesting, so If for example i do a `git rebase origin/develop` then I find that I messed up a conflict or something, I could simple do a `git reset --hard develop{1}` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady: `develop@{1}`, but yes. Use `git reflog $branch` to view the reflog a specific branch. If called without arguments, it will show the HEAD reflog.

Comment: ah ok, so `@{1}` is the history index of the commit in the reflog, thank you for the tip, (or more like the pointer history)

Comment: `git rebase --onto master topic^ topic` is exactly what I need, thx :)