# Rebase the second commit to master

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have edited some files in the repo and now it looks like the following:

```
history1 --> history2 --> ... --> master
                \
                 \
                  my commit 1 --> my commit 2
```

But actually 'my commit 2' should not be on top of 'my commit 1', that's a mistake... How do I only rebase 'my commit 2' to master in mercury?

```
history1 --> history2 --> ... --> master
                \                   \
                 \                   \
                  my commit 1        my commit 2
```

I am asking how to do this in **Mercurial** not git.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the rebase extension enabled in your hgrc file. Then:

```
$ hg rebase -r <commit ID of my commit 2> -d master
```

See "hg help rebase" for more details.

Answer (score -1):

From a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635672/git-rebase-a-single-commit):

You can cherry-pick XX to master.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <commit ID of XX>
```

And remove the last commit from the feature branch with git reset.

```
git checkout Feature-branch
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Comment: Well, I am asking in mercurial... let me update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, sorry I missed that.