# How to copy files and changes in one branch to other branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

Suppose I cloned `branch1` and made new branch `branch2` where I made changes to some files. However some new files are added in `branch1` after that and some changes are made in previous files of branch1. I want those files and changes to be also in `branch2`. How to do this using git ?

```
branch1->some new files added and some previous files modified
|
|cloned
|
branch2->modified few files->add new files in branch1 here also as well as changes in old files
```

Can we use rebasing here ?

I will try to elaborate more pictorially :

```
branch1-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h
|
|
|clone
|
|
branch2-x-y-z
```

What I want :

```
branch1-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h
|
|
|clone
|
|
branch2-x-y-a-z-b-c-d-e-f-g-h
```

How to use rebasing here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get just one file from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch)

Comment: the new files in branch1 are in one commit without other changes?

Comment: @mfort  some changes in previous files of branch1 are made and some new files are added too.  I want those changes in branch1 to reflect in branch2. Can I use rebasing here ?

Comment: @isherwood I have more than one new files in branch1 and some changes in old files are made. I want them to reflect in branch2. Should I use rebasing ?

Comment: @KRS7784 yes you can rebasing here and also can use cherry-pick.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635672/rebase-a-single-git-commit

Comment: @mfort there might be multiple commit in branch1 and branch2 . Can you write answer (list of commands) on how to proceed. Should I used commands mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563319/git-rebase-basics  ? I am in fear and I don't want to do any damage to branch1 . Could you please write answer if you know.

Answer (score 1):

git checkout source_branch paths

Example from branch sourceBranchName
we get file Test.java

1. Create new branch:

   git checkout -b targetBranchName
2. Get state of Test.java file from the sourceBranchName to current branch without autocommit: git checkout sourceBranchName path to file or dirrectory:

   git checkout sourceBranchName pathTo/Test.java

Comment: I have multiple files in branch1, How to copy all of them into branch2 ? Can we use rebasing here ? Because some files which are common in branch1 and branch2, some changes have been made in them also

Comment: As far as I know the method above is working for directories too. Try to use
git checkout sourceBranchName pathToDir/* The * means all files in dir. Also wildcards for files names can be used instead the *. Use extended GIT documentation in the official website.

Comment: If files in the sourceBranch have been already committed, you can use cherry pick to get all of them.

Comment: I have elaborated more on what I want to do in question

Comment: just merge branch1 into the branch2

Comment: Will that destroy changes I did in branch2 ? For example I wrote some extra line of codes in xyz.java in branch2, will those changes get reverted or lost ?

Comment: If u have crossing changed files, resolve conflicts and chose correct code during merge procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The sample way is to use cherry-pick
for example:

```
git checkout branch2
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

this copy the commits that you want from branch1 to branc2
and it does not affect branch1 at all

If you want to get all the changes from branch1, use git merge branch1 in branch2

Comment: If I merge will that destroy changes I did in branch2 ? For example I wrote some extra line of codes in xyz.java in branch2, will those changes get reverted or lost ?   Can I use first answer provided here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893399/rebase-feature-branch-onto-another-feature-branch

Comment: I think you'll just go from brunch2 to a new branch and do all your experiments there
for example `git checkout -b branch3` run it from branch2

Comment: will cherry-pick revert my changes in branch2 if they are not in branch1 ?

Comment: cherry-pick not revert you changes if they are not in branch1

Comment: does rebasing takes lot of time, after following accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893399/rebase-feature-branch-onto-another-feature-branch, on terminal it's showing $(branch2|REBASE 1/5)